# Processing user request in a separate activity

Tags: android

I want to have a loading activity that processes log in and register requests ,I tried to start loading activity from log in and register activities ,and start processing in onstart() function,but if screen goes off and on onstart() calls again and process repeats ,I don't know oncreate() method is good place for this or not,and if there is another approach.

Comment: Provide the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Start up an Activity for result, with startActivityForResult()

Like this, you can have the started activity do your stuff, and return a value.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html